# Android - Getting and modifying the same List from two different activities

Tags: android, list, android-activity

In my App I have crated a `MyList.class` which looks like this:

```
public class MyList {

private ArrayList<Obj> objList = new ArrayList<>();

//adds object to list
public void addObjToList(Obj obj) {
    objList.add(obj);
}

//gets the whole list
public static ArrayList getObjList() {return objList;}

//gets the size of the list
public static int getObjListSize() {return objList.size();}

//removes obj from list based on his position
public void removeObj(int pos) {
    objList.remove(pos);
}

}
```

From the `CreateObj.class` where I create the `Obj` I have this code to add it to the `objList`:

```
// creates the new object
Obj newObj = new Obj("Name", 3 /*int*/ );

// creates a new List
MyList myList = new MyList();

// adds the obj into the list
myList.addObjToList(newObj);
```

It successfully adds the obj to the list. Now from my `Main_Activity.class` I need to retrieve it and inflate it into a recyclerView, which I do in the `onCreate()` method like this:

```
currentObjList = MyList.getObjList();

//puts list into recycler
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,
         LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, currentObjList);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Notice that I do not set `MyList myList = new MyList()` in my Main_Activity because I want the list to be the one created in the CreateObj class.

Obviously this is not the right way to do it, because if, let's say I want to delete an element from the recyclerView, I need to remove it from the objList (in the MyList.class) too, and that's not possible since I cannot access the MyList.class methods without setting a `new MyList()`, and if I do set it to new, It would not keep the Obj added from the CreateObj class.

In short: How can I have the same objList to be both accessible and modifiable from both, CreateObj.class and Main_Activity.class.

Comment: store object in Arraylist and remove that object when you need to modify and you are not implementing correct form of pojo

Comment: @jagapathi could you please be more specific? this is exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: pass your myList reference to recycler adapter so that you no need to create new object for your mylist class

Comment: Why does the CreateObject class also create the MyList instance? Should't the MyList instance be created in the MainActivity? It seems each new object goes in a new list...

Comment: @Juan yes you are probably right the new Instance should go in the main activity, but I would still have the same problem then in the CreateObj class since there I need to add the obj to the MyList

Comment: I think you have to look into the logic of how your app will work. Who is creating the Object? That activity should have a reference to both, CreateObje and to MyList. Then the activity would first create the object using CreateObj and then pass it to the instance of MyList to be added to the internal ArrayList.

Comment: @Juan The CreateObj class itself is creating the object based on user input. So it should have a reference to what? Main_Activity?

Comment: I have added an answer below explaining with more detail my last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment this is a draft of what I was suggesting.
Please note I haven't ran this code so it must have errors and typos, it is just to reflect the idea of what I was proposing.

The Activity that receives the input holds a referenct to the class that creates the object and to the class that holds the ArrayList.

Upon user input, the activity asks the object creator to create an ojbect and passes it back to the activity. Then the activity adds it to the list.
And finally it notifies the recycler adapter that the data has changed.

In MainActivity:

```
    private CreateObj createObj;
    private MyList myList;

    //Other memeber variables for Input elements on the screen
    //used in createObje.create() to build the new object.

    public void onCreate(...){
      ...
      createObj = new CreateObj();
      myList = new MyList();

      currentObjList = MyList.getObjList();

      //puts list into recycler
      recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
      recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,
         LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

      adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, currentObjList);
      recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

      ...    

      aUserConfirmInputElement.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()){
          public void onClick(){
             Obj obj =  createObj.create();
             myList.addObjectToList(obj);

             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
      }

      ...
}
```